# How can i show data present inside the nested elements using map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

Please tell me how can i access the nested objects in arrays 
I have pasted the code below and I want to access the nested objects using
only through map function.

```
Data=[
  {name:'Amir'},
  {name:'jamile'},
  {name:'hali'}
]


const result=Data.name.map( (name)  => name);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `const result = Data.map(({ name }) => name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either by accessing the property using `.` operator or by destructing.

```js
let Data=[
  {name:'Amir'},
  {name:'jamile'},
  {name:'hali'}
]


const result=Data.map( ({name})  => name);

console.log(result);

const result2=Data.map( (name)  => name.name );

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks its working....

Comment: @YasirBajwa always happy to help :)

Comment: I have one more issue Thats is my first experience to ask the question on stack overflow i dont have any idea hope you dont mind the way i ask question but i will improve it. now i have a list  like const data=[{name:'Yasir',salary:1000},{name:'Ahmad',salary:9000},{name:'Zain',salary':20000} now i want to filter the data and  the object is return whose income is more than 4 digit .

Comment: @YasirBajwa what do you mean by 4 digit can it be `0000`. ?

Comment: I mean salary lenght like 1000 have 4 digit length and and i want to filter the data whose length is greater than 4.

Comment: yes it may be 0000

Comment: @YasirBajwa add the input and desired output in question itself. will update my answer. and also these conditions

Comment: it may be any num at  this time i only want length more than 4 integer.

Comment: const newdata=Data.filter(i=> salary.length > 4); but its not working and also i m facing some issue to edit the question thats why i post in comment.please tell me the solution here.

Comment: @YasirBajwa this should be `i.salary.length`   const newdata=Data.filter(i=> i.salary.length > 4);